# Feature Engineering: extracting the effect of email newsletter

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidyverse, modeling

Im quite new to machine learning and applied modeling. Currently iam working on a forecast project and collect various data for my features. I often times read that only choosing standalone features is not enough and that you want to extract new features based on existing ones.

Imagine a company send out a new years newsletter and i have the following tibble with columns date and mail, where 1 in the mail column stands for newsletter was send and 0 stands for no newsletter was send

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble <- tibble(date=as_date(1:31, origin="2019-12-31"),
                 mail=factor(c(1, rep(0,30))))
```

```
# A tibble: 31 x 2
   date       mail 
   <date>     <fct>
 1 2020-01-01 1    
 2 2020-01-02 0    
 3 2020-01-03 0    
 4 2020-01-04 0    
 5 2020-01-05 0    
 6 2020-01-06 0    
 7 2020-01-07 0    
 8 2020-01-08 0    
 9 2020-01-09 0    
10 2020-01-10 0    
# ... with 21 more rows
```

Based on the mail feature i want to build a new feature that represets kind of a lagged mail effect since customers neither instantly check their mails nor not instantly visit the shop rather or consequently buy something. So the effect may be there for 4 or 5 days.

I simply could add `1` to the following 4 dates. But i cannot imagine that this would be best practice. So my question is what the best practice would be to model such effects.

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Please be more specific about what type of ML you are using. Any form of feature engineering must take into account both what you are trying to predict, which is unclear in the OP, and what ML method you are using to predict, which is not stated.

Comment: Iam trying to predict sales of 200 different articles with an xgboost model

Comment: Please revise your original post to make it completely clear what you are trying to achieve. Feature engineering is, by its nature, specific to each problem. It is still not clear what you are trying to predict and what data you are using. You are trying to predict sales, but did not mention sales in the OP. And what sales are you trying to predict? Are you trying to predict sales for an individual? On aggregate? Again, without that kind of information it is not possible for anyone to give you helpful advice on what kind of feature engineering could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you want a column (feature) that represents whether the newsletter was sent at anytime in the last 4 days? The `lag` function can help:

```
tibble %>%
  mutate(mail_lagged = 
           as.numeric(
             mail == 1 |
             lag(mail, 1) == 1 |
             lag(mail, 2) == 1 |
             lag(mail, 3) == 1 |
             lag(mail, 4) == 1))

# A tibble: 31 x 3
   date       mail  mail_lagged
   <date>     <fct>       <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01 1               1
 2 2020-01-02 0               1
 3 2020-01-03 0               1
 4 2020-01-04 0               1
 5 2020-01-05 0               1
 6 2020-01-06 0               0
 7 2020-01-07 0               0
 8 2020-01-08 0               0
 9 2020-01-09 0               0
10 2020-01-10 0               0
# … with 21 more rows
```